# Google Analytics E-Commerce Event Not Appearing in Conversions

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-analytics

I'm facing an issue with Google Analytics E-Commerce tracking, specifically related to the E-Commerce events not appearing in the Conversions section. Here's the relevant code snippet I'm using in my Next.js app:

```
import UniversalAnalytics from 'universal-analytics';

if (
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS &&
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
) {
  const visitor = UniversalAnalytics(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS,
    payment.email
  );

  visitor
    .event('Ecommerce', 'Purchase', {
      value: data.Transactions[0].Total,
    })
    .send();
}
```

Despite successfully sending events, I cannot see any data in Google Analytics under the Conversions > E-Commerce section. The error message I'm getting in Google Analytics is Incompatible request.